# Top menu disapears in Category Pages when filtering using ACF

Tags: php, categories, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) and filtering the results using the method they posted on their website.

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/tutorials/creating-wp-archive-custom-field-filter/

Filtering works fine, however, top menu disappears when the result is displayed. The code I am using is below:

In functions.php
    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');

function my_pre_get_posts( $query )
{
    // validate
    if( is_admin() )
    {
        return;
    }

```
// get original meta query
$meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

    // allow the url to alter the query
    // eg: http://www.website.com/events?location=melbourne
    // eg: http://www.website.com/events?location=sydney
    if( !empty($_GET['bedrooms']) )
    {
        $bedrooms = explode(',', $_GET['bedrooms']);

        //Add our meta query to the original meta queries
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => 'bedrooms',
            'value'     => $bedrooms,
            'compare'   => 'IN',
        );
    }

// update the meta query args
$query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

// always return
return; 
}
```

In category.php

```
    <div id="search-houses">
    <?php 

    $field = get_field_object('bedrooms');
    $values = explode(',', $_GET['bedrooms']);

    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $field['choices'] as $choice_value => $choice_label ): ?>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $choice_value; ?>" <?php if( in_array($choice_value, $values) ): ?>checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> /> <?php echo $choice_label; ?></li>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {

    $('#search-houses').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){

        // vars
        var $ul = $(this).closest('ul'),
            vals = [];

        $ul.find('input:checked').each(function(){

            vals.push( $(this).val() );

        });

        vals = vals.join(",");

        window.location.replace(location.pathname + '?bedrooms=' + vals);

        console.log( vals );

    });

})(jQuery); 
</script>
```

Demo:
http://thepursesociety.com/_web/category/houses

Comment: Have you read the Codex page for [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)?

Comment: I did and tried to understand, but my knowledge is very limited with PHP and coding. Do you know what am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`pre_get_posts` in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts):

> **Identifying Target Queries**
>
> When using pre_get_posts, be aware of the query you are changing. One useful function is is_main_query(), which can help you ensure that the query you are modifying is only the main query. Use it in combination with other conditional tags to only alter the main query on the pages you want.

`pre_get_posts` is executed for *every query* on a page, which includes the query that loads your menu items, so you need to check if `$query->is_main_query()` before you modify it, otherwise you'll apply your query modifications to other queries.

Comment: Thanks a million! Solved it. Theme was using $query->is_main_query().